# Rotate a vector based on a normal in Three.js

Tags: javascript, math, vector, three.js

I have a vector like this

```
{x: 0, y: 0, z: 1}
```

Then I have another vector that is a normal, a direction, like this

```
{x: 1, y: 0, z: 0}
```

How do i rotate the vector based on the direction in the normal so it looks like this?

```
{x: 1, y: 0, z: 0}
```

I'm using Three.js

Comment: You want a general rotation that rotates vector a into b? (a and b given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging in to this answer I come up with a solution that seems to work
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1486

```
rotateVectorWithNormal(toRotate: Vector3, normal: Vector3) {

    const newVector: Vector3 = new Vector3().copy(toRotate);

    // set up direction
    let up = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    let axis: Vector3;
    // we want the vector to point in the direction of the face normal
    // determine an axis to rotate around
    // cross will not work if vec == +up or -up, so there is a special case
    if (normal.y == 1 || normal.y == -1) {
        axis = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    } else {
        axis = new Vector3().cross(up, normal);
    }

    // determine the amount to rotate
    let radians = Math.acos(normal.dot(up));
    const quat = new Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axis, radians);
    newVector.applyQuaternion(quat);

    return newVector;

}
```

Code in Typescript

Comment: If someone want's a good explaination of this, try to google Rotation Matrix and Quaternion

Answer (score 1):

While the auto-answer is correct, here some general points about such a rotation:

If only two vectors are given, namely `a` and `b`, there are infinite rotations transforming `a` into `b`. The answer above takes the shortest rotation but requires to determine the axis of rotation via a cross product. A second solution is to take the bisector as rotation axis and rotate by `Pi`. Here you would normalize to `a_n` and `b_n` and rotate around `(a_n + b_n)`.

The difference between the rotations would only affect non-rotational symmetric object.

If all vectors are normalized already it should be as simple as

```
var a = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
var b = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
var c = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( a + b, Math.PI );
c.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
```

If `c==a` then `c` is rotated onto `b` and if `c==b` then `c` is rotated onto `a`.